# Callback of locationChanged in Mapbox Android

Tags: android, kotlin, location, mapbox

How to implement the callback for locationChanged in Mapbox Android for Kotlin?
I want to perform some operations on every location update of the user.

I couldn't find anything in docs. Probably, it's really simple.

Thank you,

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/5.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener.html

Comment: What @LorenceHernandez has linked is a tiny bit outdated, you can check out https://docs.mapbox.com/android/core/overview/#requesting-location-updates instead. The core library linked above is already a part of the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android. You can also read more about the `LocationComponent` in https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/location-component/

Comment: thanks @ŁukaszPaczos, I've found the solution

Answer (score 1):

It worked checking the link Lukasz Paczos mentioned.
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/core/overview/#requesting-location-updates